# Adding two R.id in a single TextView in xml

Tags: android, xml

I have two `android:id` .

For example: [ `R.id.custom_font` ] and [ `R.id.product_name` ]

In .java file

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jcc.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(cFont);

// Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name,  products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I put them together in a single text view it shows an error message  [Attribute "android:id" was already specified for element "TextView"]

In .xml file

```
    <TextView

        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/custom_font"
        android:id="@+id/product_name" //Attribute "android:id" was already specified for element "TextView"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
```

How can I pass the two android:id in a single text view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just reference the TextView by the single id

Comment: Could you please help me... [Download This](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/To-Use-Custom-Font.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can have only one `android:id` associated with one component.

Comment: if you are looking for listview with custom font. Then better the use customize adapter. where by you can do it in getView(int position, View convertView1, ViewGroup parent) method. You can Google for customization of ListView Adapter examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of having two IDs for one view...

Just use the `R.id.custom_font` again in the following line:

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.custom_font,  products);
```

Comment: If I put this way; </br> `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.custom_font, R.id.product_name,  products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);` </br> It does not work.

Comment: It works either <br/> `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.custom_font, products); lv.setAdapter(adapter);`<br/> or `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products); lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Of course...`adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.custom_font, products); lv.setAdapter(adapter);` is exactly why I said in my answer...

Comment: Then `R.id.product_name` doesn't pass and don't show my product.

Comment: I appreciate your cordial help... [Download This](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/To-Use-Custom-Font.zip)